# Django: Save an uploaded file to a FileField

Tags: django, filefield

I feel a little stupid for having to ask this… But I can't seem find it documented anywhere.

If I've got a `Model` with  `FileField`, how can I stuff an uploaded `FILE` into that `FileField`?

For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    file = FileField(...)

def handle_post(request, ...):
    mymodel = MyModel.objects.get(...)
    if request.FILES.get("newfile"):
        mymodel.file = request.FILES["newfile"]
```

But that doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Well, my suspicions were confirmed: I am an idiot :)

The method I outline in my question is, in fact, correct — it wasn't working because I'd forgotten to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form.

Anyway, I'll leave this question here, just incase other people have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also had issues with file not really posted to server when name attribute was not specified in input tag

```
<input type="file" name="somename">
```